# How should we tag Jedi Knight 2: Jedi Outcast?

Tags: discussion, tags

I created the tag [jk2-jedi-outcast](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jk2-jedi-outcast) because [jedi-knight-2-jedi-outcast](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jedi-knight-2-jedi-outcast) it 1 character too long. Any other suggestions, or should we leave it be.

At the moment one question.

Comment: Could we drop the second 'Jedi' and just call it [jedi-knight-2-outcast]?

Comment: Thought of that for a moment, that's also a possibility. I played the game long ago, I have no clue what the community (if there's one) calls it

Comment: Yeah, I don't know much about the game personally, but at least when entering it as a tag, if people type 'Jedi outcast' they'll still get the tag as it should match on both words

Comment: If it matters for searching jedi-knight-2-outcast sounds good. If search somehow works differently or on an expanded version I think jk2-jedi-outcast is the nicer abbreviation.

Comment: If you asked me, I'd tag em with a synonym [jedi-outcast] -> [jedi-knight-2], maybe even a reference to a set of [dark-forces] tags. I think we're trying too hard making explicitly worded tags when they should be (IMHO) synonyms.

Comment: @Robotnik jedi-knight-2-outcast has all of the words spelled out, and simply omits the second jedi, so that seems better than one that's an abbreviation and doesn't have "knight" anywhere in it

Comment: @DCShannon - Yeah that's what I was thinking.

Comment: would typing `jedi outcast` show [jedi-knight-2-outcase]?

Comment: @Aequitas I was assuming it would, but maybe not. I went to the "tags" tab and tried typing in "mass 3", but mass-effect-3 does not show up. "Knight" finds jedi-knight-jedi-academy, but "knight academy" does not. From the "ask a question" page, "knight academy" enters knight and academy as separate tags, and knight-academy doesn't find anything. Kinda crappy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Based on [Thunderforge's suggestion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11202/how-should-we-tag-jedi-knight-2-jedi-outcast/12790?noredirect=1#comment40872_12790), the tag name is now [star-wars-jedi-knight-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-jedi-knight-2).**

This was done to keep the tag name consistent with the last game in the series. I've also expanded the tag names for other games in the *Jedi Knight* series, as they fit within the 35 character limit.

- [star-wars-jedi-knight](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-jedi-knight) → [star-wars-jedi-knight-dark-forces-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-jedi-knight-dark-forces-2) (*Star Wars Jedi Knight: Dark Forces II*)
- [jk2-jedi-outcast](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jk2-jedi-outcast) → [star-wars-jedi-knight-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-jedi-knight-2) (*Star Wars Jedi Knight II: Jedi Outcast*)
- [jedi-knight-jedi-academy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jedi-knight-jedi-academy) → [star-wars-jedi-knight-jedi-academy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-jedi-knight-jedi-academy) (*Star Wars Jedi Knight: Jedi Academy*)

---

<s>Now that the maximum tag length has been [increased to 35](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12497/181240), I've gone ahead and retagged the two questions about this game.</s>

The tag name is now [jedi-knight-2-jedi-outcast](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jedi-knight-2-jedi-outcast).

Comment: The previous game in the series is currently tagged as [star-wars-jedi-knight]. Sadly [star-wars-jedi-knight-2-jedi-outcast] is 36 characters long. Would it be better to instead rename it to [star-wars-jedi-knight-2] to match the previous game?

Comment: @Thunderforge That’s a good idea. It’s important to maintain consistency in naming.

Comment: Looks like there is also [\[star-wars-jedi-outcast\]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-jedi-outcast) as a tag. I don't know if you have the power to create synonyms, but making that a synonym of [star-wars-jedi-knight-2] would be great.

Comment: @Thunderforge I have renamed the tags. However, I am not able to create or suggest tag synonyms.